# How to make variable global outside foreach loop in php?

Tags: php, variables, foreach, global

**I am fetching data from table in foreach loop. Now i am trying to use variable outside for each loop but its not working.**

```
public function get_all_folders()
            {
                $con = $this->__construct();
                $sql="select * from documents";                
                $execute = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                $rows = mysqli_num_rows($execute);
                $data = [];
                while ($result = $execute->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $data[] = $result;
                }
                return $data;
            }
```

above is my function to fetch data on another page.

```
 $folder = $obj->get_all_folders();        
        foreach ($folder as  $folder_data) 
            {

                $existing_directory = $folder_data['root_dir'];
            }
```

**On another page i am calling my function on the top of my page.Inside foreach loop my variable `$existing_directory` is working.
But if i used this variable outside loop its not showing data.**

Comment: what are you getting in `$existing_directory` if you use outside loop. And what is desired output?

Comment: so you have to declare it outside the loop first. But also right now you will just overwrite the value every time the loop runs. So maybe you want an array instead. It's not clear what final result you actually want.

Comment: Have you included first page file in your second page file?

Comment: @B.Desai inside loop im getting my data from column `root_dir` but outside its empty

Comment: Why would you want to copy parts of `$folder` to another variable, you already have everything available there.

Comment: @Ishpreet im calling my class on another page

Comment: @amitsutar: for class also, you have to include first file in your second page

Comment: yup bro its included

Comment: The value of last iteration may be nothing that's why $existing_directory doesn't output any data outside foreach.

Comment: Also $folder, may also contain 0 elements. That's why no data is set to  $existing_directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the variable outside loop if you want to access it outside as well.

```
$folder = $obj->get_all_folders();        
$existing_directory = null;
foreach ($folder as  $folder_data) 
{
   $existing_directory = $folder_data['root_dir'];
}
```

as per your code you will get last record from array
so you can try below code as well

```
$folder = $obj->get_all_folders();        
$last_record = end($folder);
$existing_directory = $last_record['root_dir'];
```

Answer (score 0):

In second page, first of all, include first page as below:

```
include_once 'file1.php';    // whatever your filename
```

Secondly, create object of class (class in first file) in second file as shown below:

```
$obj = new className();          // whatever classname you have provided in file1
```

If still not work, then write below statement before your foreach statement in second page:

```
print_r($folder);exit;
```

If nothing displayed, means there is no data, and therefore foreach will not show anything.

Answer (score 0):

Make it like this. In foreach loop you are assigning value to $existing_directory make it $existing_directory[] otherwise it will override previous variable.

```
$existing_directory = array();
$folder = $obj->get_all_folders();        
  foreach ($folder as  $folder_data) 
    {
      $existing_directory[] = $folder_data['root_dir'];
    }
```

Comment: its working but showing error of array to string conversion

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\client_test\pages\add_documents.php on line 68

Comment: i can create folder into folder but it store as array not as `root_dir`

Comment: It's understood if you store in array it will return array, the problem is some where if you want single folder name you've to identify which folder you want to access.